# My First react-native program is not running on emulator

Tags: react-native

I am a beginner in react-native. And create a project named **AwesomeProject** by this cmd

> **react-native init AwesomeProject**

And try to run it by this cmd

> **react-native run-android**

But i m getting an error while runing,

**Could not run adb reverse: Command failed: adb -s emulator-5554 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081**

Also attaching a screen-shot of terminal,
[image]

And something is shown on the emulator which is attached below.

[image]

Please suggest me how can i do to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using adb from 'android-tools-adb', you might get this error because it does not have support for 'reverse' which is required for reversing socket communications back to device. If that is the case, go on reading further.

Try using the adb provided by Android Studio which has the support for 'reverse'. Android studio has adb present in platform-tools inside your Android Sdk path. (Generally /home/your-user-name/Android/Sdk on ubuntu machines.)

You can use one of below commands to use the correct adb executable based on your preference,

> `sudo ln -s /home/<user>/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb /usr/local/bin`
>
> `sudo ln -s /home/<user>/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb /usr/bin`

Try running the emulator again.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have installed your packages(i.e. npm install). Can I see your file structure.